# function to recount on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a validation function onclick. When you click on the button initially, it goes through each field and makes sure the validations are good or not. It currently only tells me via console how many errors there are, or if there were no errors.

It works the first time! But when I fix the error and click the button again, it still says that there is an error from before it was fixed.

My question is, is there a way to have the button recount or "refresh"? Here is the code that I have

```
function moveOn(){
    if (errors > 0) {
        console.log(errors);
    } else if(errors === 0){
        console.log("no errors!");
    }
};
```

here is the rest of the code

```
var errors = 0;
function validate(){


$(".validName").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var minLength = defaultMinNameLength
    //check data-min-length if exists then 
    // min length = thatValue
    if (validateName(val) && validateLength(val,minLength)){
        inlineValidate(this, { '.error': 'hide', '.correct': 'fadeIn', '.incorrect': 'hide' },"#ccc");
    } else {
        errors++;
        inlineValidate(this, { '.error': 'fadeIn', '.correct': 'hide', '.incorrect': 'fadeIn' }, "#ff9999");
    }
});

$(".validLetNum").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var minLength = defaultMinNameLength
    if (validateLetterNum(val) && validateLength(val,minLength)){
        inlineValidate(this, { '.error': 'hide', '.correct': 'fadeIn', '.incorrect': 'hide' },"#ccc");
    } else {
        errors++;
        inlineValidate(this, { '.error': 'fadeIn', '.correct': 'hide', '.incorrect': 'fadeIn' }, "#ff9999");
    }
});

$(".validEmail").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var minLength = defaultMinNameLength
    if (validateEmail(val) && validateLength(val,minLength)){
        inlineValidate(this, { '.error': 'hide', '.correct': 'fadeIn', '.incorrect': 'hide' },"#ccc");
    } else {
        errors++;
        inlineValidate(this, { '.error': 'fadeIn', '.correct': 'hide', '.incorrect': 'fadeIn' }, "#ff9999");
    }
});
// console.log(errors);
};

function moveOn(){
    if (errors > 0) {
        console.log(errors);
    } else if(errors === 0){
        console.log("no errors!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Not enough info here - how is `errors` variable being set?

Comment: You need to reinitialise `errors` each time you correct them. Maybe when you click the button.

Comment: Set errors=0 inside the function where you validate the fields

Comment: Nico, do you mind elaborating? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *possibly* fix the issue by changing:

```
var errors = 0;
function validate(){
```

To:

```
var errors;
function validate() {
    errors = 0;
```

**NOTE**: From your code it's not very clear how you call `moveOn()` (or even whey you call `validate()`) so I cannot confidently confirm that the above should fix your issue.

**CAUTION**

- Try not to clutter the global scope. You want to use localized variables. If you need to use a variable like `errors` in another function, pass that variable to the second function, or that may be an indication that your two functions should be combined into one.
- Separate your JS code from your HTML. Rather than use an element's `onclick` attribute, it is better to leverage the power of jQuery and bind a `click` event to the element instead.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you! I call moveOn() with an onclick attribute in the html

Comment: Glad I could help. :-) Usually providing the relevant HTML snippet is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveOn(){
    if (errors > 0) {
        // Correct errors
        errors = 0;
    } else if(errors === 0){
        console.log("no errors!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Joshua. When I try this it always says there are 0 errors